# cannot convert 'ArithProgression*' to 'Progression*' in assignment

Tags: c++, inheritance, codeblocks, dynamic-binding

I had defined a class "Progression" and saved it as "Progression.h" and then i made another class "ArithProgression" which extends Progression class and saved it as "ArithProgression.h".

File: Progression.h

```
#ifndef PROGRESSION_H
#define PROGRESSION_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Progression
{
public:
    Progression()
    {
        cur=first=0;
    }
    Progression(long f)
    {
        cur=first = f;
    }
    void printProgression(int n)
    {
        cout<<firstValue();
        for(int i=0;i<=n; i++)
        {
            cout<<' '<<nextValue();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Progression() {}
protected:
    long first;
    long cur;

    virtual long firstValue()
    {
        cur= first;
        return cur;
    }
    virtual long nextValue()
    {
        return cur++;
    }
};

#endif // PROGRESSION_H
```

FILE: ArithProgression.h

```
#ifndef ARITHPROGRESSION _H
#define ARITHPROGRESSION _H
#include "Progression.h"
class ArithProgression :public Progression
{
public:
    ArithProgression(long i=1)
    :Progression()
    {
        inc=i;
    }
    virtual ~ArithProgression () {}
protected:
    long inc;
    virtual long nextValue()
    {
        cur+=inc;
        return cur;
    }
private:
};
#endif // ARITHPROGRESSION _H
```

FILE: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Progression.h"
#include "ArithProgression.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Progression* p;
    p= new ArithProgression();
    p->printProgression(10);
    delete p;
}
```

I am getting an error: "cannot convert 'ArithProgression*' to 'Progression*' in assignment" in code blocks 12.11

Please Help

Comment: There's no such error in this code. Are you sure this is the code you're compiling?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't enough information here to guess why your IDE might be compiling the wrong thing. Perhaps you have other headers with the same names on the search path? You could try looking at the preprocessed source to see exactly what's being included.

Comment: ya, when i checked the file directory there were two ArithProgression.h files.
thanks now it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as you posted it, [works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bc887d0213eca6c). Since `ArithProgression` is indeed a subclass of `Progression`, the above code cannot trigger that error.

Comment: did u made different file for each class?

Comment: @user3005403, doesn't matter because if you had problems with files inclusion you would get an error at the `#include` lines. Not after.

Comment: ya, but it is showing this error. Can you please try by making different files?

Comment: @user3005403, try deleting the output and `.o` files and recompile everything.

Comment: @user3005403: I copied the code, as posted, into three separate files, and it compiled without error (just a warning about the rogue space in `ARITHPROGRESSION _H`). Are you sure you're compiling this exact code?

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, i am using the same code and using code blocks as IDE

Comment: I dont know how, but when copy the same files to another project it works.
thank you for ur help :)